# Filling the data in an Android bitmap as quickly as possible from C

Tags: java, android, c, bitmap, java-native-interface

I've managed to get an android.graphics.Bitmap created and I'm successfully filling it via the SetPixels command.

The problem is that I start off with RGBA data.  I then create a jintArray.  I then call SetIntArray (effectively memcpying the data into the buffer).  Then, finally, I call setPixels to actually set the pixels (which presumably causes another copy).

one big issue with doing this is that whether I used R8G8B8A8 or R5G6B5 or A8 I still have to convert my pixel data to R8G8B8A8 data.

Ideally I'd like a way to fill the buffer using only one copy and allow me to do it without doing the pixel format conversion.

Is there any way to directly get at the buffer data contained in a Bitmap? I see there is a function GetDirectBufferAddress in the JNI, but the documentation I can find on it suggests its limited to a java.nio.buffer.  Can I directly get at the pixel data using this function? Perhaps by getting the internal buffer used by the Bitmap class?

Is my only way of using this to create a Global Ref'd Java.nio.buffer then each time I want to update, copy my pixel data into it and then use copyPixelsFromBuffer?  This still involves 2 copies but can, at least, eliminate the pixel format change.  Is this going to be any more efficient than the method I'm already using?

Is there an even better way of doing it?

Btw, I *AM* aware of the fact I can use the functions in < android/bitmap.h > but I would really like to not lose support for Android 2.1 and Android 2.2 ...

Cheers in advance!

Comment: 2.2 does support <android/bitmap.h>, so you'll only lose 2.1. At this point, I don't think that's such a big loss...

Comment: Direct Bitmap pixel access is possible also on 2.1 (even on 1.5), I use it, tested to work, but it's kind of hacking in NDK. If you can, go ahead to use official bitmap.h and AndroidBitmap_lockPixels / AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels.

Comment: @mice `I use it, tested to work, but it's kind of hacking in NDK` - Would you care to post the details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here comes a dirty yet working solution, working from Android 1.5 up to 4.0.
Code is in C++.

```
                              //decls of some partial classes from Skia library
class SkRefCnt{
public:
   virtual ~SkRefCnt(){}
private:
   mutable int fRefCnt;
};

//----------------------------

class SkPixelRef: public SkRefCnt{
public:
   virtual class Factory getFactory() const;
   virtual void flatten(class SkFlattenableWriteBuffer&) const;
protected:
   virtual void* onLockPixels(class SkColorTable**) = 0;
   virtual void onUnlockPixels() = 0;
public:
   void *GetPixels(){
      SkColorTable *ct;
      return onLockPixels(&ct);
   }
};

jobject java_bitmap;  //your Bitmap object
jclass java_bitmap_class = env.GetObjectClass(java_bitmap);
class SkBitmap;
SkBitmap *sk_bitmap = (SkBitmap*)env.CallIntMethod(java_bitmap, env.GetMethodID(java_bitmap_class, "ni", "()I"));
SkPixelRef *sk_pix_ref;
sk_pix_ref = (SkPixelRef*)((int*)sk_bitmap)[1];
// get pointer to Bitmap's pixel memory, and lenght of single line in bytes
int buffer_pitch = env.CallIntMethod(java_bitmap, env.GetMethodID(java_bitmap_class, "getRowBytes", "()I"));
void *buffer = sk_pix_ref->GetPixels();
```

Comment: What exactly is the skia library?

Comment: Part of Android. Graphics library tightly connected to Java classes (Canvas, Bitmap, Paint). So it's always there, on every device.

Comment: Cool.  Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: What exactly? Skia is in Android source code, you can download it and study. Java sources are also available.

Comment: Thanks, this is working almost out of box and saved many hours.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, static method:

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap (int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)
```

does nor involve copying data, but creates (immutable) bitmap structure  over existing  pixel array. This way you can prepare such bitmap in advance,  and then manipulate buffer from your 
native code. This shall support  different pixel formats. Example of Usage is available here:

http://javaocr.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/javaocr/trunk/demos/recognizer/src/net/sf/javaocr/demos/android/recognizer/Recognizer.java?revision=239&view=markup

( Line 520 )

Comment: It has to perform a copy.  Otherwise how does it change from an int array to an "ALPHA_8" bitmap?  I don't see what your link shows, though, other than how to create a bitmap (which I can already do from C++).  However I need to *update* the image regularly and creating a new Bitmap each time is very wasteful ...

Comment: Why should it change to ALPHA_8 if my pixels are already  RGBA? My link show sample OCR applicaton for android -  there is a fair bit of  java image processing

Comment: But what if the bitmap isn't RGBA though??  I don't use RGBA because its too slow to fill the bitmap ...

Comment: then you have to copy around.  You always trade memory for speed - I decided to work with integer pixels in linear array, even if I need 1 bit. I waste a lot of memory, but I'm able to define bitmap over it without coping around.

Comment: But if you create the bitmap each time you want to modify it you are not only wasting memory and filling speed but you are wasting tonnes of time creating objects ...

Comment: I create bitmap when I like to render it.   I keep my memory buffer, and create just immutable bitmap object over it without copying it.  It does not create tons of objects.  You start with RGBA8 data, basically it is integer array.  You will gain nothing by conversion to  other formats.

Comment: Except speed, which is what this question is about ... So far the buffer method I explain above has proved to be significantly faster than the method you are suggesting.  The difference between real-time and not being able to cope with all the incoming data.